# Loading gif with jquery (load) function

Tags: jquery, loading

I am trying to find the right code syntax for putting in a "loading gif" while the load function works inserting information on to my page...

```
<script>
    ('#myinfo').load('/data/myinfo.html');
</script>
```

Do I have to put loading gif inside?

Comment: Well, you need to include the loading gif in the page so when the page loads the users will be able to see it: `<div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>`, and then you need to hide it when the page has loaded `$( window ).load(function() { $("#loading").hide() });`

Comment: Also read about [.ajaxStart()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxComplete()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) - You can use those global ajax event handlers to show the animation when any ajax request starts (Using `.ajaxStart()`) and hide in when the request is complete (Using `.ajaxComplete()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    //delay script until after the page has been parsed into the DOM
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //get a reference to whatever holds the gif, or the gif itself
        var $loadingGif = $(selectorForLoadingGif);

        //show the gif before the load starts
        $loadingGif.show();
        //load the other info
        $('#myinfo').load('/data/myinfo.html', function(){
            //this method executes after the load finishes
            //hide the loading gif
            $loadingGif.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp, this is a 2-step process with no JS:

1.Add this HTML where you want the spinner:

2.Add this CSS to make the actual spinner:

```
.loader {
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```